# Calling a Function in a Stored Proc Cursors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a function "Split" which I am calling in a stored proc with cursor.

My `a_upload` table structure is: `(int, varchar(100))`

```
upload_id   allowed_file_extensions
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1           .xls, .doc, .pdf, .docx, .xlsx, .pptx, .txt
2           .xls, .doc, .pdf, .jpeg, .jpg, .docx, .xlsx, .pptx, .txt
```

table `c_file_extensions` is: `(int, varchar(100), bit)`

```
id  description  is_enabled
---------------------------
1   .xls         1
2   .doc         1
3   .pdf         0
4   .rtf         1
```

Stored proc:

```
DECLARE @is_enabled Varchar(10), @allowed_file_extensions Varchar(100)

   SET @is_enabled = 'True';

DECLARE cur CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR 
  SELECT items 
    FROM split((SELECT allowed_file_extensions 
                  FROM a_upload 
                 WHERE upload_id = 1), ',') 

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @allowed_file_extensions
WHILE @@fetch_status=0
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
                FROM c_file_extensions 
               WHERE description = @allowed_file_extensions 
                 AND is_enabled = 0)
      SET @is_enabled = 'False';

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @allowed_file_extensions
END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

SELECT @is_enabled AS Output
```

function split:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))       
  RETURNS @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000)) AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @idx int       
    DECLARE @slice varchar(8000)       

    SELECT @idx = 1    

    IF LEN(@String) < 1 OR @String IS NULL RETURN

    WHILE @idx!= 0       
    BEGIN       
        SET @idx = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String)       
        IF @idx != 0       
          SET @slice = LEFT(@String,@idx - 1)       
        ELSE       
          SET @slice = @String       

          IF(LEN(@slice)>0)  
            INSERT INTO @temptable
             (Items) 
            VALUES
             (@slice)       

          SET @String = RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - @idx)       
          IF LEN(@String) = 0 BREAK
    END  
RETURN      
END
```

For `upload_id = 1`, I am expecting the output to be '`False`', but I always get '`True`'. I tried to debug, and found that the "`if exists (select * from c_file_extensions where description = @allowed_file_extensions and is_enabled = 0)`" is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're comparing against items with leading spaces.

Try this:

```
  select items from split((select ext from a_upload where id = 1), ',')
```

This results in:

```
.xls
 .doc
 .pdf
 .docx
 .xlsx
 .pptx
 .txt
```

To solve this, you could:

- modify your cursor definition:

```
select  LTRIM(items) from split((select ext from a_upload where id = 1), ',')
```

- modify your `dbo.split()` to remove leading spaces on Line 29:

```
set @String = LTRIM(right(@String,len(@String) - @idx))
```

Comment: ahh leading spaces :( Thank you campbell, it worked. Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you